# How to best store data when working with recursion, and reset the data if method is re-called

Tags: java, recursion, integer

I'm tasked with searching recursively and iteratively for a string in a given input. More specifically I need to ensure that all parentheses brackets have an opposite one to match it. My code returns true if paratheses are all matched and false if they aren't. My problem is with the recursion as I'm struggling to track the parentheses. My code beneath works perfectly when called once, but if I call it multiple times the integers cross-track and it causes out of bounds exceptions. I want to know the best way that I can store the values when calling the function, as well as how I can reset the integers when the function gets called again.

In other words, how can I reset these numbers after calling the code so that it works when called again, and what's the best way to track a number within recursion?

```
public static int tempSpot = 0; // this integer stores the position of the string im at
                                // since I'm not allowed to use a for loop to serve the same purpose
public static int openCount1 = 0; // track the count of "("
public static int closeCount1 = 0; // track the count of ")"

    public static boolean balanceParenthesesRecursive(String str){
        if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == '(') {
            openCount1++;
        }
        if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == ')') {
            closeCount1++;
        }
        tempSpot++;
        if (tempSpot == str.length()) {  // prevents recursion if next call will be out of bounds
            return openCount1 == closeCount1;
        } else {
            balanceParenthesesRecursive(str);
        }
        return openCount1 == closeCount1;
    }
```

Comment: The best way is not to have a static method, that way it will be reset every time you create a new instance of the class. Otherwise, create a new starter method called `initiateBalanceParenthesesRecursive` that simply resets the 3 storage values (tempSpot, holderValue1, holderValue2) to 0. And when you want to use the recursion call the new method, but have that method call your existing method `balanceParenthesesRecursive`

Comment: When I remove static from the integers, I get an error stating that they cant be called from a static context. Do you know a way around that so I can update or call on them without them being static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, you do not need to "store" any data. You may pass the data as parameters to the next recursion loop. Something like that:

```
public static boolean balanceParenthesesRecursive(
    String str, int tempSpot, int openCount, int closeCount
) {
    if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == '(') {
        openCount++;
    }
    if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == ')') {
        closeCount++;
    }
    tempSpot++;
    if (tempSpot == str.length()) {
        return openCount == closeCount;
    } else {
        return balanceParenthesesRecursive(str, tempSpot, openCount, closeCount);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Positive result = " + balanceParenthesesRecursive("this is (positive) test string.", 0, 0, 0));
    System.out.println("Negative result = " + balanceParenthesesRecursive("this is (negative)) test string.", 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Update:
You said that you have a requirement that the method should accept only one parameter (the string).
There is an alternative, but it is really ugly one. To clear the static variables when the work is done:

```
public static int tempSpot = 0; // this integer stores the position of the string im at
// since I'm not allowed to use a for loop to serve the same purpose
public static int openCount1 = 0;
public static int closeCount1 = 0; // track the count of "(" or ")"

public static boolean balanceParenthesesRecursive(String str){
    if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == '('){
        openCount1++;
    }
    if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == ')'){
        closeCount1++;
    }
    tempSpot++;
    if (tempSpot == str.length()){  // prevents recursion if next call will be out of bounds
        boolean result = openCount1 == closeCount1;
        tempSpot = 0;
        openCount1 = 0;
        closeCount1 = 0;
        return result;
    } else {
        return balanceParenthesesRecursive(str);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Positive result = " + balanceParenthesesRecursive("this is (positive) test string."));
    System.out.println("Negative result = " + balanceParenthesesRecursive("this is (negative)) test string."));
}
```

Alternative #2. Maybe it's ok to "wrap" recursive method into non-recursive:

```
public static boolean balanceParenthesesRecursive(
    String str, int tempSpot, int openCount, int closeCount
) {
    if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == '(') {
        openCount++;
    }
    if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == ')') {
        closeCount++;
    }
    tempSpot++;
    if (tempSpot == str.length()) {
        return openCount == closeCount;
    } else {
        return balanceParenthesesRecursive(str, tempSpot, openCount, closeCount);
    }
}

public static boolean balanceParentheses(String str) {
    return balanceParenthesesRecursive(str, 0, 0, 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Positive result = " + balanceParentheses("this is (positive) test string."));
    System.out.println("Negative result = " + balanceParentheses("this is (negative)) test string."));
}
```

Comment: Parameters would be very helpful, however, it's required for the assignment that when the method is called on it only takes one parameter, that being (String str). That was something I should have mentioned.

Comment: @BanksN ok, I see. Then, you can, of course, clean up those variables (I've edited my answer). You may also have a dedicated class, that would accept the string in the constructor and then you'd have a method, but then it also won't match the requirement: the method will accept 0 params. Also you can create a method (non recursive) with 1 string parameter and call the recursive method inside.

Comment: Your first alternative worked just fine! Assigning the boolean to a value, then clearing the other two so that I can check the value even after clearing the first two holders worked fine. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The existing answer is good, but to address your comment, the following is a solution without using static variables by making use of an instanced class/object.

First, we create a new class, for this example, I used `SomeClass` as follows, and note how nothing is static:

```
public class SomeClass {

    //Variables will be reset to the below values every time you create a new instance of this object
    private int tempSpot = 0;
    private int openCount1 = 0;
    private int closeCount1 = 0;

    public boolean balanceParenthesesRecursive(String str) {
        if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == '(') {
            openCount1++;
        }
        if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == ')') {
            closeCount1++;
        }
        tempSpot++;
        if (tempSpot == str.length()) {  // prevents recursion if next call will be out of bounds
            return openCount1 == closeCount1;
        } else {
            balanceParenthesesRecursive(str);
        }
        return openCount1 == closeCount1;
    }
}
```

Then to call this class and use the method we first need to use `new SomeClass()` to create an instance of the class, then we can call the method and get the result like so:

```
Boolean result = new SomeClass().balanceParenthesesRecursive(yourString);
```

---

Side note, a better solution might be to merge both of my suggestions to have both a starter method and still keep the methods instanced to the class (not static). This is a safer option, but is not necessary in most cases and does not need to be non static. Note how the starter method is public, and the recursive method with the variables is private so it can not be accessed from outside of the class/object:

```
public class SomeClass {
    
    //public starter method that starts the values at 0
    public boolean balanceParenthesesRecursive(String str) {
        return balanceParenthesesRecursive(str, 0, 0, 0);
    }
      
    //tempSpot stores the position of the string im at
    //openCount1 tracks the count of "("
    //closeCount1 tracks the count of ")"
    private boolean balanceParenthesesRecursive(String str, int tempSpot, int openCount1, int closeCount1) {
        if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == '(') {
            openCount1++;
        }
        if (str.charAt(tempSpot) == ')') {
            closeCount1++;
        }
        tempSpot++;
        if (tempSpot == str.length()) {  // prevents recursion if next call will be out of bounds
            return openCount1 == closeCount1;
        } else {
            balanceParenthesesRecursive(str);
        }
        return openCount1 == closeCount1;
    }
}
```

You would use the new class instance and method call to get results from this second option:

```
Boolean result = new SomeClass().balanceParenthesesRecursive(yourString);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand it: 1. How your implementation helps from the initial problem? The method "balanceParenthesesRecursive" still can be called only once as the counters are not cleaned up 2. What is the point of creating stateless class? Maybe I'm missing something? Creating a new class instance for every next call? What's the point? Then you could make, at least, "str" as a field, so the usage would be at least safe.